# Nth-of-type works just like nth-child, I can't select what I want in a very simple markup

Tags: html, css

Please see this codepen or the following screenshot and code: https://codepen.io/rockmandash/pen/YbJQqG

My HTML

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="line"></div> I want to select this element(second line)
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="line"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 150px;
}

.child {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: green;
  margin: 6px;
}
.line:nth-of-type(2) {  I chosed, but not working as expected
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background: black;
}
```

Screenshot

[image]

Why my nth-of-type works just like nth-child?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[`:nth-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type)** matches the `nth` sibling of a given **type** (such as `<div>`).

Because the `.line` elements are `<div>` elements, with `.line:nth-of-type(2)` you're essentially stating that you want to target the second sibling element which has the same **type** as `.line`:

```
div
    div
    div - target
    div
    div
```

This turns out to be the **first** `.line`.

What you probably want is `.line:nth-of-type(4)`, or, less confusingly, `div:nth-of-type(4)`:

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 150px;
}

.child {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: green;
  margin: 6px;
}

.line:nth-of-type(4) {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="line"></div> I want to select this element(second line)
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="line"></div>
</div>
```

Note that there is no such thing as an `:nth-of-class`, so you will likely need to assign a unique class or ID to the element if you don't want to use such a complex selector.

Answer (score 1):

The `:nth-of-type(n)` selector matches every element that is the nth child, of a particular type(like `div and p`), of its parent and `:nth-child(n)` selector matches every element that is the nth child, regardless of type, of its parent.

So use `nth-child` or span instead of `div` for `line class`

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 150px;
}

.child {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: green;
  margin: 6px;
}

.line:nth-of-type(2) {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background: black;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <span class="line"></span>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <span class="line"></span> 
  <div class="child"></div>
  <span class="line"></span>
</div>
```